# Retrieving PHP Session Variables After Manually Setting Session ID

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP script that manually sets a PHP session ID and variables.

However, am unable to subsequently retrieve session variables even though session ID remains the same.

Sample code

```
if ($_GET['request'] == 0) {// new request
    echo "new request\n";
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    session_id(md5($id));
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = "joe";
    echo "SESSION CONTENT: ".json_encode($_SESSION);
    echo "\n";
    echo "SESSION ID: ".session_id();
    echo "\n";
}else { // subsequent requests
    echo "subsequent request\n";
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    session_id(md5($id));
    session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    echo "SESSION CONTENT: ".json_encode($_SESSION);
    echo "\n";
    echo "SESSION ID: ".session_id();
}
```

Output is:

**new request

SESSION CONTENT: {"name":"joe"}

SESSION ID: 5cebd1165cf619fcc332998a087c6414

subsequent request

SESSION CONTENT:[]

SESSION ID: 5cebd1165cf619fcc332998a087c6414**

Why is the $_SESSION array empty in subsequent requests?

Comment: On the second go, I only need to retrieve and not set. Because the session was set on first go.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: session_id() needs to be called before session_start().
So what you see is what I have. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: No - `session_start()` must always be called first and preferably *outside* of your check.

Comment: Thanks.
From the PHP docs, it says:
"If **id** is specified, it will replace the current session id. session_id() needs to be called before session_start() for that purpose."

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: What you should do is set the session id and start the session outside of your condition check.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried that, same result. Both session_id and session_start are outside the condition check. Any reasons, you think this might do it?

Comment: Without being able to put the code into action there is really not enough to go on here. What little testing I have been able to do, worked.